# Which kind of STL should I use for this task?

Tags: c++, list, stack, queue

I need a queue that must add/remove some structs I have, such as:

```
struct MyObject
{
  int offset;
  BYTE status, data1, data2;
  double beatPos;

  enum Status
  {
    isOff = 8,
    isOn = 9,
  };
}
```

When I `.Add()` an element, this queue must put the element at the correct position, due to the `beatPos` value, which must be ordered from the lower (top of the queue, i.e. the next element I'll pop) to the upper (the last element I'll extract from it).

I see there is [std::priority_queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue), but I'm not sure if I can select which is the field for the ordering.

Also, once I add some structs in the list, I'd like to remove the first element that have (for example) `beatPos=1,567` (which could be in the middle of the list, for example; not necessarily at the beginning).

Any clues?

Comment: can multiple `MyObject`s can have the same `beatPos` value?

Comment: @Zaiborg: yes of course!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `std::multiset` with a user-defined comparator.  For example:

```
bool MyObjectComp(const MyObject& lhs, const MyObject& rhs) {
    return lhs.beatPos < rhs.beatPos;
}

typedef std::set<MyObject, MyObjectComp> MyObjectSet;
```

Now the ordering within `MyObjectSet` is always from lowest to highest `beatPos`.  You can search using `lower_bound()` and `upper_bound()`, and you can get the smallest value using `begin()`.

Note that due to the nature of `double` values (IEEE floating point), exact comparison may not work, so you can't necessarily say `mySet.find(0.5)` but you can say `mySet.upper_bound(0.49999)`.

The same user-defined comparator can be used for `priority_queue` as well, but that container does not support searching for an element by value, which is one of your requirements.

Comment: Good answer but this fails for the OP's requirement that there can be multiple objects with the same `beatPos`

Comment: @NathanOliver: Good point, I changed `set` to `multiset`.  The rest is the same.

Comment: Looks like we both wound up getting to the same place ;)

Comment: And no love for std::multimap  ;-)

Comment: @VolkerK: There's no reason to want a map here, since the key is intrinsic to the value.  It'd be a waste of space.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: and than how I `.Add()` or `.Remove()` these elements? Can you give to me an example?

Comment: @paizza: You use the `.insert()` and `.erase()` methods of the multiset.

Answer (score 6):

What you want is a [`std::multiset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset).  It takes a compare template parameter and it is defaulted to `std::less` for the type the container is going to store but you can specify a different comparator.  To do that we can create a lambda that will compare two `MyObject`s and return which object should have a higher priority based on the `beatPos` member

```
auto my_compare = [](const MyObject & lhs, const MyObject & rhs)
                    {
                        return lhs.beatPos < rhs.beatPos;
                    }
```

And then we can use that like

```
std::multiset<MyObject, decltype(my_compare)> data(my_compare);
```

This will give you an ordered container that can store multiple objects with the same `beatPos` and allow you access into the middle of the container.

Comment: This does not support finding arbitrary `beatPos` values in the container and removing them, which is a requirement in the question.

Comment: Good answer for the first part of the question, but as @JohnZwinck says, `priority_queue` is no good for accessing by key..

Comment: @JohnZwinck I missed that part of the requirement.  It is fixed now.